# How to sort array of objects and shift some type of strings to end of the list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort array of objects by "name" key. Here some values starts with 'summer', after sorting need to place those objects to be end of the list. Have any idea look this sorting once.

This is my list:

```js
var list = [
    { name: 'Summer_Mango', id: 20055 },
    { name: 'Orange', id: 20053 },
    { name: 'Apple', id: 45652 },
    { name: 'Grape', id: 20066 },
    { name: 'Summer_Watermelon', id: 20073 },
    { name: 'Banana', id: 20010 }
];
```

After sorting my list need to come like this

```js
var list = [
    { name: 'Apple', id: 45652 },
    { name: 'Banana', id: 20010 }
    { name: 'Grape', id: 20066 },
    { name: 'Orange', id: 20053 },
    { name: 'Summer_Mango', id: 20055 },
    { name: 'Summer_Watermelon', id: 20073 }, 
];
```

Comment: Please share your attempt(s), together with a description of what goes wrong. Stack Overflow is not for "please write some code for me" assignments - you are expected to show some attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: You really tried [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), checked examples, related questions and it did not work?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @tevemadar I'm able to do sort by using sort() method but "Summer_Mango" and "Summer_Watermelon" not able to shift to the end .

Comment: Have you checked the duplicate? This should work: `list.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`

Comment: It works fine with localeCompare: https://jsfiddle.net/s0mzjfuy/ (and it would also work with a longer function using `<` and `>`)

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks you so much, It is working fine..But I'm not able to understand that logic.

Comment: @adiga Yes your statement working fine..thank you :)

Comment: @tevemadar please don't edit questions with your comments or answers

Comment: @adiga OP asked for an explanation, and I was about 30 seconds late after the topic got closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize sort condition for your requirement.

```
list = list.sort((a, b) => { 
   if (a.name.startsWith('Summer')) {return 1; } 
   if (b.name.startsWith('Summer')) {return -1;} 
   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) 
});
```

```js
var list = [
    { name: 'Summer_Mango', id: 20055 },
    { name: 'Orange', id: 20053 },
    { name: 'Apple', id: 45652 },
    { name: 'Grape', id: 20066 },
    { name: 'Summer_Watermelon', id: 20073 },
    { name: 'Banana', id: 20010 }
];

list = list.sort((a, b) => { 
   if (a.name.startsWith('Summer')) {return 1; } 
   if (b.name.startsWith('Summer')) {return -1;} 
   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) 
});

console.log(list)
```

Comment: Don't think you have to have seperate handling for moving `Summer` to the end. OP wants those at the end simply because those are the last items alphabetically :)